# $\omega$-categoricity and infinite languages

Tags: model-theory

The Ryll-Nardzewski Theorem states that an equivalent condition to $\omega$-categoricity is that there is a finite number of $n$-types for any $n$.
So what happens when you add a countably many unary predicate to the signature of an $\omega$-categorical theory?

Two examples:

- Let $\mathcal{G}_1$ be infinite empty graph, augmented with predicates $P_i$ each true on $i$ vertices.
- Take an enumeration of rigid graphs $(G_i)$ of increasing size, such that $P_i$ is true only on the vertices of $G_i$. Let $\mathcal{G}_2$ to be the union of these graphs.

How many models do the theory of these graphs have? Can they all obtained by some standard model-theoretic construction?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is an "infinite *empty* graph"? Infinitely many vertices, no edges? Surely there's a better term than "empty".

Comment: @BrianO Yes, that's it. If you prefer, you can call it an "infinite anticlique".

Comment: Two comments: 1. Your second example doesn't appear to be an example. That is, $\mathcal{G}_2$ isn't $\omega$-categorical even if you forget the $P_i$. 2. The question is a little unclear. Are you just asking "What can happen if we expand an $\omega$-categorical structure with infinitely many unary predicates?" At that level of generality, the answer is going to be "just about anything" (in fact, adding just *one* predicate to the theory of the random graph can give you a very complicated theory indeed, if the subgraph picked out by the predicate is complicated enough).

Comment: @AlexKruckman For $\mathcal{G}_2$, it depends if it constructed carefully enough right? 
Regarding 2, in both cases I see a possible axiomatization of the resulting theories, but fail to see what could be a model other than the 'intended model'. The question is actually what is below the examples, can we say something about the number of possible models ($\omega$?), and is it possible to build some (all?) via standard constructions.
Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Oh, when you wrote "let $\mathcal{G}_2$ to be the union of these graphs", I understood this to mean "disjoint union". I guess you intended the $G_i$ to form a chain under inclusions whose union is the random graph? In both of your examples, you can get countable models which aren't the "intended model" by realizing the type $\{\lnot P_i(x)\mid i\in \omega\}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh, I get it (thanks!).  
So we can't say anything more in the general case then? Or can we (that there should be at least $\omega$ many models for example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Let $M$ be our $\omega$-categorical structure, and let $\hat{M}$ be $M$ expanded by the predicates $\{P_i\mid i\in\omega\}$ and say that two predicates $P_i$ and $P_j$ are equivalent if they have the same interpretation on $M$. As you note, Ryll-Nardzewski tells us that in an $\omega$-categorical theory, there are only finitely many $1$-types, so $\text{Th}(\hat{M})$ has no hope of being $\omega$-categorical, unless the new predicates are partitioned into only finitely many equivalence classes (i.e. if we only really added finitely many predicates). But even if we only add $1$ predicate, we can still get a theory which isn't $\omega$-categorical, see point 4.
2. Here's an example where we easily get $2^{\aleph_0}$-many countable models. Let $M$ be an infinite set (a structure in the empty language), and interpret the $P_i$ so that for any finite sets $X,Y\subset \omega$ such that $X\cap Y = \emptyset$, there exists an $x$ such that $\hat{M}\models P_i(x)$ for $i\in X$ and $\hat{M}\models \lnot P_i(x)$ for $i\in Y$. Then there are already continuum-many quantifier-free $1$-types consistent with $\text{Th}(\hat{M})$, so this theory has continuum-many countable models.
3. You can also get exactly $n$ models for any $n\in \omega$, $n \neq 2$ as an expansion of DLO with countably many unary predicates. Take the [standard examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69/complete-theory-with-exactly-n-countable-models) and replace the constant symbols with predicates that pick out exactly one element.
4. It's a fun fact (see Section 5.5 of Hodges' big *Model Theory*) that for any first-order structure $N$ in a finite language $L$, there is a graph $G$ such that $N$ and $G$ are bi-interpretable. Given a countable structure $N$, let $G$ be the (countable) graph which interprets it, and let $M$ be the random graph. Then $G$ embeds in $M$, since $M$ is universal for countable graphs. Let $P$ be a new predicate and expand $M$ to $\hat{M}$ by letting $P$ pick out the copy of $G$ in $M$. Then $\text{Th}(\hat{M})$ interprets $\text{Th}(G)$, which interprets $\text{Th}(N)$. So, for example, by adding a single predicate to the random graph we can obtain a theory which interprets ZFC set theory.

Comment: Great answer with good pointers. Thank you.